# how to group two columns in one column order by id python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Hy I have a dataframe with the following structure

| Id | Vehicle1 | Vehicle2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | motorcycle |
| 2 | bike | car |
| 3 | motorcycle | bike |

And I want to group in one dataframe with onlyone column vehicle with that structure

| Id | Vehicle |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car |
| 1 | motorcycle |
| 2 | bike |
| 2 | car |
| 3 | motorcycle |
| 3 | bike |

how can I do it with python/pandas?

I tried with groupby but i failed.

Thanks!

Comment: `df.set_index("Id").stack()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index("Id").stack()
```

This will sort all elements with the same Id by their respective column order.

Comment: Please note that there is no need to answer a duplicate questions like this one.